# Converting a UNIX Timestamp to seconds/minutes/hours/months/years using C

Tags: c, date, unix, timestamp

Using C, I want to convert a UNIX Timestamp number to several usual date data.

How do I convert a UNIX timestamp like 12997424 to different numbers representing seconds, minutes, hours and days while using C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `gmtime` or `localtime` from standard library. Prototypes are defined in time.h.

ADDED & EDITED:

So for example, the following code prints current timestamp, hour and minute:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void main() {
    time_t      t;
    struct tm   ttm;

    t = time(NULL);
    printf("Current timestamp: %d\n", t);
    ttm = * localtime(&t);
    printf("Current time: %02d:%02d\n", ttm.tm_hour, ttm.tm_min);
}
```

Comment: +1 Marian for the correct answer but it may be worth fleshing out with an example, so OP can see how to use the calls and the resulting `struct tm`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm not very experienced with programming (in C). Im trying to understand how I can convert the UNIX timestamp (which represents seconds from 1 January 1970 till the date that has been set in the code that I am using) to the several date data but I'm unfortunately not getting it at all. Where can I pass in the UNIX timestamp data (in seconds) so that it can be converted?

Comment: @Klyner the variable t of type time_t is the Unix timestamp. You can understand `time_t` type as being an `int`.

Comment: Thanks! That explains a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use localtime to convert time_t to tm as local time (credit goes to www.cplusplusreference.com):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
  printf ("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));

  return 0;
}
```